# Get the attribute, split, and insertBefore as a HTML DOM without jQuery/appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

For example I have some code:

```html
<div id='varian'>
 <a title='A, B, C, D'></a>
 <a title='1, 2, 3, 4'></a>
 <a title='1,2, E,3, C, Z2'></a>
</div>

<script>
var varianproduka = document.querySelectorAll('#varian a');
varianproduka.forEach(function(e) {
    var aa = e.getAttribute("title"),
        ba = aa.split(", ");
    for (var ca in ba) {
        var da = ba[ca],
            ea = "<div>" + da + "</div>";
        e.insertBefore(ea, e.childNodes[0]);
    }
});
</script>
```

I want to make it like this:

```
<div id='varian'>
 <a title='A, B, C, D'>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
 </a>
 <a title='1, 2, 3, 4'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
 </a>
 <a title='1,2, E,3, C, Z2'>
  <div>1,2</div>
  <div>E,3</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>Z2</div>
 </a>
</div>
```

But all I got was an error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Is there something wrong with the code? Or we really can't do this if we don't use jQuery or appendChild. The reason I don't use jQuery and append is they don't work on iOS.

Comment: Are you sure that's the result you want. If your code were to work correctly, the order of elements added would be the reverse of the title elements since that's what `insertBefore()` does

Comment: I can also assure you that there are thousands of sites using jQuery that work perfectly in iOS.

Comment: @Phil Oh I mean jQuery `.append()` can't work in iOS, so I won't use it.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Answer (score 1):

`"<div>" + da + "</div>"` is a string. You need a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

That being said, I'm not sure why you're using `insertBefore()` since you're just appending new elements in order. I recommend [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) instead which can accept multiple elements at a time.

```js
// just a simple tag creator utility
const createTag = (tagName, textContent, props) =>
  Object.assign(document.createElement(tagName), { textContent }, props)
  
document.querySelectorAll('#varian a[title]').forEach(tag => {
  tag.append(...tag.title.split(", ").map(str => createTag('div', str)))
})
```

```css
a { display: block; margin: .5rem 0; padding: .5rem; border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<div id='varian'>
 <a title='A, B, C, D'></a>
 <a title='1, 2, 3, 4'></a>
 <a title='1,2, E,3, C, Z2'></a>
</div>
```

According to the [Browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Browser_compatibility) and [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_parentnode_append) for `append()`, you should have no problem on Safari iOS (from version 10).

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertAdjacentHTML to insert node in form of string to an element.
In your code just change

```
e.insertBefore(ea, e.childNodes[0]);
```

with

```
e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',ea);
```